# Random deviations of pert distribution

Tags: r, montecarlo

I'm working with monte carlo using R with the following code:

A)

```
mc_matrix = 1

for (i in 1:1000000){
  mc_sample = rpert(n=1,min=629,max=1049,mode=739)
  mc_matrix = rbind(mc_matrix, mc_sample) 
}
mean(mc_matrix)
```

B)

```
mean_of_matrix = rpert(1000000, min=629, max=1049, mode=739)
```

Should these two instances of code not be the same? How come I'm not getting the same average having so many samples from the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

as first it would be good to let everybody know the packages you need. In your case it is the package "freedom".
Than, the newest version needs the input with `x.min`, `x.max` and `x.mode`.

In a Monte Carlo simulation you simulate random variables to calculate for example the mean as in your example. The problem is that this is just an asymptotic approximation of the distribution.

If you try this with the implemented `rnorm(n)` function you get different results for the mean, even if the true mean of every simulated normal distributed random variable is the same.

So if you try

```
mean(rnorm(10000))
mean(rnorm(10000))
```

the results will slightly differ.

Every programming language has an implemented pseudo random variable generator. If you need the same random variables again and again you can use the function `set.seed(seed)` to start the random variable generator at the same point.

Try

```
set.seed(100)
mean(rnorm(1000))

set.seed(100)
mean(rnorm(1000))
```

you will get the same results.

You can try this with your example, but the results will still differ because you do some calculations in the first example while you just calculate the mean in the last. But you are right that the results should be the same with the same random variables because it's the same calculation.

Thats a basic principle of Monte Carlo Simulations to simulate n, with n large, random variables to approximate an asymptotic distribution.